# .WAV files won't play in Firefox 24.0

Tags: windows-7, firefox, audio, windows-media-player

Environment:

Windows 7 x64

Firefox 24

Microsoft Windows Media Player Firefox Plugin 1.0.0.8 is installed and enabled

Settings under FF Options/Applications are as follows:

Wave Sound - "Use Windows Media Player (default)" **!!! Please note that "Use Microsoft Windows Media Player plugin" is not available in drop-down list for this type !!!**

Windows Media Audio File - "Use Microsoft Windows Media Player plugin"
All other types starting from "Windows Media" - "Use Microsoft Windows Media Player plugin"

**Apple Quicktime is NOT installed (I have no need for it).**

What I experience is that embedded WAV files do not play. They do play in Chrome v 30.0.1599.10 and in IE 10.0.9200.16721. They also play on my other computer that does have QuickTime installed.

I experienced this first on http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/test - when I click on speaker item to hear pronunciation pop-up window opens but nothing plays. Pressing on speaker in popup window does nothing. Clicking on "Click here to listen with your default audio player." correctly opens file in Windows Media Player and plays it.

**If I enlarge popup window there is a message "A plugin is needed to display this content". Pressing on "Install plugin" wants to install "Apple Quicktime" which I don't want and shouldn't need because I have other plugins for .WAV files.**

As it turns out there was a bug reported in FF 22 that apparently was fixed:

http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890516

Sample page in bug description (http://www.messianictrust.org.uk/parashiyot/mattot-10.php) doesn't work for me either - when pressing on either of the buttons I get "A plugin is needed to display this content". Pressing on "Install plugin" wants to install "Apple Quicktime".

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Some clarification: when I put about:plugins in the address bar there are no entries for audio/x-wav and audio/wav on computer that has this problem. So it looks like Microsoft Windows Media Player Firefox Plugin 1.0.0.8 doesn't support these file types, which doesn't make sense if you ask me.  My laptop that doesn't have a problem has entries for both types both in VLC and QuickTime section. And QuickTime is picked as a player for these files in browser options.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too and I experienced this first on merriam-webster.com.

When trying to install QuickTime Lite with the old Firefox 3 installed, the `about:plugins` page shows that the QuickTime plugin is installed and the speaker on merriam-webster.com works successfully.

When installing Firefox 7, 21 or 25.1, it fails to speak and the `about:plugins` page doesn't show the QuickTime plugin!

I found a solution by adding a registry key.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@quicktime]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\QT Lite\\Plugins\\npqtplugin.dll"
```

It seems that Firefox 3 was loading any `.dll` file in its plugins folder as a plugin automatically, but recent versions didn't.

I see that Flash player plugin has a registry key in this path.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins
```

So I made a similar one for QuickTime and I picked this name for the key "quicktime". Any name would do the job. The more important value is the path for plugin file which is in my case the `plugins` folder of QuickTime Lite.

```
C:\Program Files\QT Lite\Plugins\npqtplugin.dll
```

So, this is what I've done and it worked for me. Try it and tell me your feedback.